# How to show hidden div when closing modal window using jquery

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I am trying to show a hidden div once the user closes a modal window.  I can show hidden div when opening modal but cannot show hidden div on closing of modal window.

I am calling this function below when user clicks on Save within the modal window. Is passes information correctly to record note in record_note.php and then closes the modal but can't get it to show the div.

```
function submitAddNote() {
    var contactId = $('#contactId').val();
    var noteBody = $('#addNote').val();
    $.post('/_controller/record_note.php', {
        contactId: contactId,
        noteBody: noteBody
    },
    function (data) {
        $('#myNoteModal').modal('hide');
        $('#messageWindow').show();

    });
}
```

Comment: can you provide HTML for this?

Comment: Make sure to double check the name of the messageWindow div (copy and paste it) and make sure it's an ID and not a class. I've done that one a million times. :)

Comment: try this: `$( "#messageWindow" .removeAttr( "style" ).hide().fadeIn();`